# is there way to automate the below example

Tags: r, data.table

If i have a df like the one shown below:

```
d<-structure(list(ReviewType= c("Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Review","Review","Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction","Correction", 
                                "Deficiency", "Deficiency", "Deficiency", "Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction"),
                  Submissiondate= c("2020-08-29 04:32:00","2020-08-28 04:31:00","2020-08-26 04:31:00","2020-08-25 04:31:00","2020-08-24 04:31:00","2020-08-23 04:31:00","2020-08-22 04:31:00","2020-08-21 04:31:00","2020-08-20 04:31:00","2020-08-19 04:31:00",
                                    "2020-09-27 04:31:00","2020-09-27 03:52:59","2020-09-28 17:30:00","2020-09-29 14:01:00",
                                    "2020-09-05 03:00:00","2020-09-05 03:51:00", "2020-09-03 23:59:49",
                                    "2020-09-02 00:03:54","2020-09-01 00:04:48","2020-10-01 04:31:00","2020-10-11 04:31:00","2020-10-21 04:31:00"),
                  CaseNo= c("124","123","125","121","121","125","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","125","123","123","123","124","123","127","127","127")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))

d = mutate(d, Submissiondate = as_date(Submissiondate))
```

Usually, i would use the below code to get each case's latest detail by a specific date (in this case: 2020-08-30) and i would manually input a date to get the required results

```
Aug28<-dailysnapshot%>%filter(Submissiondate<'2020-08-30')

maxshot %>% 
  group_by(CaseNo) %>%
  filter(Submissiondate==max(Submissiondate))

FinalCounting<-maxshot%>%
  filter(ReviewType == "Correction")%>%
  dplyr::summarise(`Correction Outstanding` = n_distinct(CaseNo))

FinalCounting<-maxshot%>%
  filter(ReviewType  == "Deficiency")%>%
     dplyr::summarise(`Deficiency Outstanding` = n_distinct(CaseNo))
```

if instead of this, i have a list of list of dates such as 2020-08-30, 2020-09-06,2020-09-13, is there a data.table solution which i can use to count for each of those specific dates?

Comment: You are using `dplyr`, but then you ask for a `data.table` solution. Is that change in package intentional? It might help if you include the appropriate tag as well, whether [tag:dplyr] or [tag:data.table]. (If it isn't clear, your data above is not a `data.table`. `data.frame` and `data.table`, though very similar, are distinct in several ways.)

Comment: Also, in your data you have `character` objects, none of them are dates or timestamps. If you want to deal with them as dates or times, you need to convert them using base R `as.POSIXct`, `as.POSIXlt`, or `as.Date`, or perhaps one of the `lubridate` or `anytime` packages.

Comment: Yes, this is a sample df but in my df, they are in date format, i will edit my question. I only asked for a data.table solution because i heard its much faster with big datasets but i am fine either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look?

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate) # as_date
library(magrittr)  # just for easy-reading, not required

dates <- data.table(reportdate = as_date(c("2020-08-30", "2020-09-06", "2020-09-13"))) %>%
  .[, rdate2 := reportdate] # because DT's non-equi join tends to "absorb" a column

dates[DT, on = .(rdate2 >= Submissiondate)] %>%
  setnames(., "rdate2", "Submissiondate") %>%
  .[, .SD[which.max(Submissiondate),], by = .(reportdate, CaseNo)] %>%
  .[ order(reportdate, CaseNo), ]
#     reportdate CaseNo Submissiondate ReviewType
#  1: 2020-08-30    121     2020-08-25 Correction
#  2: 2020-08-30    123     2020-08-28     Review
#  3: 2020-08-30    124     2020-08-29     Review
#  4: 2020-08-30    125     2020-08-26     Review
#  5: 2020-09-06    121     2020-08-25 Correction
#  6: 2020-09-06    123     2020-09-05 Correction
#  7: 2020-09-06    124     2020-09-02 Deficiency
#  8: 2020-09-06    125     2020-08-26     Review
#  9: 2020-09-13    121     2020-08-25 Correction
# 10: 2020-09-13    123     2020-09-05 Correction
# 11: 2020-09-13    124     2020-09-02 Deficiency
# 12: 2020-09-13    125     2020-08-26     Review
# 13:       <NA>    123     2020-09-28 Deficiency
# 14:       <NA>    125     2020-09-29 Correction
# 15:       <NA>    127     2020-10-21 Correction
```

How this works:

- create a `dates` table which just has each of the report dates;
- because `data.table` non-equi joins (like this) causes one of our columns to be lost, I duplicate it so we can retain both the report date and the submission date
- non-equi left-join (in DT-speak, `A[B, on=.(...)]` is similar to dplyr's `left_join(B, A, by = ...)`), where all reports up to the reportdate are included for each one of the report dates. It might be informative to look at this before we reduce the data:

  ```r
  dates[DT, on = .(rdate2 >= Submissiondate)] %>%
    setnames(., "rdate2", "Submissiondate") %>%
    ### .[, .SD[which.max(Submissiondate),], by = .(reportdate, CaseNo)] %>%
    .[ order(reportdate, Submissiondate), ] %>%
    print(999)
  #     reportdate Submissiondate ReviewType CaseNo
  #  1: 2020-08-30     2020-08-19     Review    123
  #  2: 2020-08-30     2020-08-20     Review    123
  #  3: 2020-08-30     2020-08-21     Review    123
  #  4: 2020-08-30     2020-08-22     Review    123
  #  5: 2020-08-30     2020-08-23     Review    125
  #  6: 2020-08-30     2020-08-24 Correction    121
  #  7: 2020-08-30     2020-08-25 Correction    121
  #  8: 2020-08-30     2020-08-26     Review    125
  #  9: 2020-08-30     2020-08-28     Review    123
  # 10: 2020-08-30     2020-08-29     Review    124
  # 11: 2020-09-06     2020-08-19     Review    123
  # 12: 2020-09-06     2020-08-20     Review    123
  # 13: 2020-09-06     2020-08-21     Review    123
  # 14: 2020-09-06     2020-08-22     Review    123
  # 15: 2020-09-06     2020-08-23     Review    125
  # 16: 2020-09-06     2020-08-24 Correction    121
  # 17: 2020-09-06     2020-08-25 Correction    121
  # 18: 2020-09-06     2020-08-26     Review    125
  # 19: 2020-09-06     2020-08-28     Review    123
  # 20: 2020-09-06     2020-08-29     Review    124
  # 21: 2020-09-06     2020-09-01 Correction    123
  # 22: 2020-09-06     2020-09-02 Deficiency    124
  # 23: 2020-09-06     2020-09-03 Deficiency    123
  # 24: 2020-09-06     2020-09-05 Correction    123
  # 25: 2020-09-06     2020-09-05 Deficiency    123
  # 26: 2020-09-13     2020-08-19     Review    123
  # 27: 2020-09-13     2020-08-20     Review    123
  # 28: 2020-09-13     2020-08-21     Review    123
  # 29: 2020-09-13     2020-08-22     Review    123
  # 30: 2020-09-13     2020-08-23     Review    125
  # 31: 2020-09-13     2020-08-24 Correction    121
  # 32: 2020-09-13     2020-08-25 Correction    121
  # 33: 2020-09-13     2020-08-26     Review    125
  # 34: 2020-09-13     2020-08-28     Review    123
  # 35: 2020-09-13     2020-08-29     Review    124
  # 36: 2020-09-13     2020-09-01 Correction    123
  # 37: 2020-09-13     2020-09-02 Deficiency    124
  # 38: 2020-09-13     2020-09-03 Deficiency    123
  # 39: 2020-09-13     2020-09-05 Correction    123
  # 40: 2020-09-13     2020-09-05 Deficiency    123
  # 41:       <NA>     2020-09-27 Correction    123
  # 42:       <NA>     2020-09-27 Correction    123
  # 43:       <NA>     2020-09-28 Deficiency    123
  # 44:       <NA>     2020-09-29 Correction    125
  # 45:       <NA>     2020-10-01 Correction    127
  # 46:       <NA>     2020-10-11 Deficiency    127
  # 47:       <NA>     2020-10-21 Correction    127
  #     reportdate Submissiondate ReviewType CaseNo
  ```
- for each `reportdate` and `CaseNo`, take the last row with `which.max(Submissiondate)`; note that this does not check for or differentiate for *ties* ...

Comment: I used the chunks of it in my solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy using the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate) # + dplpr etc.

df = mutate(d, Submissiondate = as_date(Submissiondate))

filter(df, date %in% as_date(c("2020-08-29", "2020-10-21"))
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what i want. By taking these two dates, i would have done Aug28<-dailysnapshot%>%filter(Submissiondate<'2020-08-30') and then did the counting and then i would have used Oct06<-dailysnapshot%>%filter(Submissiondate<'2020-10-06') and then do another counting. I wanted to know if instead of doing long code, there's a short version of it

Comment: I think you can probably subset as per my answer then use group_by() and summarise() to get your answer. Sometimes dplyr can be a bit cumbersome if you have a lot to do with each sample, you can get around it by using `do` or group_split + map, or just a for loop in many cases. I can't give you an exact answer because I'm not sure what you want exactly.